# How do I translate between .net type to postgresql type?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

So, I need to create an SQL query to alter my table columns. This require me to be able to write as a string the name of the type I require. However, I can only know that during runtime, and only as a .net type (for example "string" or "int").

This means I need to use some sort of function that takes in a .net type (or a string representing that type), and return a string for it's PostgreSQL type. (For example, "String" should be returning "TEXT", and "int" should return "INTEGER").

Is there any sort of a way to do that with Npgsql?

Thanks

Comment: Build a dictionary of those translations, e.g. `"string" -> "text"` etc?

Comment: Obviously I can do always that, but that would take a long time and might have mistakes in it. I would expect Npgsql to have it already built in.

Comment: Sometimes the same .NET type can correspond to multiple PostgreSQL types; for example a string can correspond to `text`, but also `varchar`, `text`, `json`... What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Npgsql may be able to provide some default mappings, but the problem isn't as simple as it seems. To be honest what you're asking for is a type mapping feature of a full-fledged ORM - are you sure your scenario really requires this kind of fully dynamic typing?

Comment: Npgsql is an ORM provider for EF. Your question makes no sense.